# difference between DictionaryLearning and MiniBatchDictionaryLearning in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to write some code for `Dictionary Learning` by using `scikit-learn` lib in `Python`. But I found two function, Both function looks like same.

I want to know what is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DictionaryLearning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning.html) is a full-batch method, where the whole data is kept in memory during learning.

[MiniBatchDictionaryLearning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchDictionaryLearning.html#sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchDictionaryLearning) is a minibatch method (only n=minibatch-size items need to be in memory within each iteration), where `partial_fit` (= fit on minibatch) is supported to work on bigger instances without hitting memory too hard.

While the general idea is the same, these algorithms are different and target different use-cases.

If you can use the former with your memory, use it. If not, use the latter.

If using the minibatch-variant, keep in mind, that there is still an open bug in regards to [partial_fit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6779).

A general overview about large-scale computing and escpecially incremental-learning within sklearn (where MiniBatchDictionaryLearning is mentioned) can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html). It also mentions the downside: tuning the hyperparameter minibatch-size.

Comment: i have an another question about sparse coding. is there have any centralized sparse coding function in scikit-learn??

Comment: @SudipDas What do you mean by centralized? DictionaryLearning is sparse-coding.

Comment: we generally find a sparse code from a dictionary to get a better signal,but the method or formula to find the sparse code(generally called alpha) is different in centralized sparse code

Comment: The approaches within the module [decomposition](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.decomposition) is all there is i think. It sounds you want a different loss-function, but well, maybe you will have to implement it yourself. I think sklearn is heavily relying on [sparse_coder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.SparseCoder.html#sklearn-decomposition-sparsecoder) for this which supports different algorithms, but i suspect the loss is always the same despite additional weights.

Comment: @i have tried both, in MinibatchDictionaryLearning(), it is taking 3 or 4 min to learn dictionary bt in DictionaryLearining() learning, still now i din't get any result ..after 2 hour i just stopped the program. why it is happening ??  if i  get both results then i can compare with 2 different functions output.. so,can u help me??

Comment: @SudipDas As far as i remember you are learning on huge dimensions. This is not what is usually done. I'm not giving advice here, but all Deep-Learning or SVM-based approaches are working on something like 80x80 or similar.

Comment: is dictionary learning not a good process to denoise a image??

Comment: Well, i remember some papers doing that and the results sure were good. But i don't remember the computational resources. So, as stated in your other question, without adding runnable code there is not much to help. (I'm pretty sure, those papers used different optimization-algorithms, not targeted as the ones in sklearn, which are more built towards ML in general)

Comment: yea r8, I think i need to write my own function for that ,One think what u want to say by runnable code??

Comment: I mean: make your problem reproducible for us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136861/discussion-between-sudip-das-and-sascha).